# How to create new SBT configuration with its own Main?

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to create a new `Configuration` in an SBT Scala project with its own main class. Here are the basic requirements:

1. Production application code is located in `<project root>/src/main/scala/com/example/Main.scala`:

```scala
package com.example

object Main extends App {
  println("Hello from Main!")
}
```

2. The main class I'm trying to run should be located in `<project root>/src/qa/scala/com/example/QAMain.scala`:

```scala
package com.example

object QAMain extends App {
  println("Hello from QA!")
}
```

(As suggested by the path, the actual use-case for this is a version of the application for QA to run that bypasses certain time-consuming operations.)

3. This main class should be runnable by executing `sbt qa:run` in the project root directory.
4. (Nice to have): The classpath of the running application should not contain any of the test classes defined under `src/test`.

Here's a `build.sbt` that I feel *ought* to work, but doesn't:

```
lazy val QA = config("qa").extend(Compile)

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .configs(QA)
  .settings(
    (sourceDirectories in (QA, compile)) += baseDirectory.value / "src" / "qa",
    (mainClass in (QA, run)) := Some("com.example.QAMain"),
    (mainClass in Compile) := Some("com.example.Main")
  )
```

Unfortunately, the result is

```
> sbt qa:run
...
[info] Running playground.Main 
Hello from Main!

> sbt "qa:runMain com.example.QAMain"
...
[info] Running com.example.QAMain 
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.QAMain
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.QAMain
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / runMain) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

That last line is interesting, because it looks like SBT is running the task scoped to the `Compile` configuration instead of my custom `QA` configuration. `sbt inspect` confirms this.

My assumption has been that since a configuration's `compile` task uses the `sourceDirectory` setting, that an override of that setting will force an override of any task downstream of that setting. This assumption might be wrong in a couple of different ways:

1. `sourceDirectory` may not be upstream of `compile`, but maybe some other setting is that I could change;
2. `compile` might need to be explicitly overridden anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear which-all settings were upstream of `compile`, but there's apparently enough of them that you need to use `sbt.Defaults`:

```
lazy val QA = config("qa").extend(Compile)

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
  .configs(QA)
  .settings(
    inConfig(QA)(Defaults.compileSettings) : _*
  )
```

This achieves the desired behavior. To test this, add the following classes:

`<project root>/src/main/scala/com/example/Water.scala`

```
package com.example

class Water {
  def drink(): Unit = {
    println("Cool and refreshing")
  }
}
```

`<project root>/src/qa/scala/com/example/Poison.scala`

```
package com.example

class Poison {
  def drink(): Unit = {
    println("You have died of dysentery.")
  }
}
```

Then SBT is happy to build an instance of `Water` into `QAMain`, but will not find `Poison` to build into `Main`.